# Chrome extension Manifest warning regarding icons type

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, manifest.json

Setting up a Preact Chrome extension and getting a warning of ***Manifest: property 'icons' ignored, type array expected.*** Although manifest.json seems to be set correctly.

[image: Chrome extention warning.]

manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "name",
    "version": "1",
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "assets/icons/icon16.png",
            "48": "assets/icons/icon48.png",
            "128": "assets/icons/icon128.png"
        }
    },
    "description": "descr",
    "icons": {
        "16": "assets/icons/icon16.png",
        "48": "assets/icons/icon48.png",
        "128": "assets/icons/icon128.png"
    },
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "index.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this a bunch of times over the years and it's always baffled me, though it hasn't ever caused me problems. My guess is that there's a bug in Chromium that's causing this... perhaps some way in which... OH.

I had this line in my html file:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

and when I removed that the error message went away.

The two manifest files are similar but for different purposes, and they have different formats—the link-rel one is for progressive web apps ([Web Application Manifest](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/)), and it DOES require a `icons` as an array ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/icons)). The use of manifest.json for both of them is dumb; fortunately the PWA one seems to be moving towards `site.webmanifest` as a default filename.

Whereas the one that wants `icons` as an object is the [Chrome Extension Manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/).